# CASE conditions (WHEN, IN) and COALESCE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running a PostgreSQL query like this:

```
SELECT way, way_area,
  CASE COALESCE(landuse, leisure, highway, amenity, tourism)
    WHEN 'industrial' THEN 'industrial'
    WHEN 'park' THEN 'park'
    WHEN 'common' THEN 'park'
    WHEN 'garden' THEN 'park'
    WHEN 'playground' THEN 'park'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS class
FROM planet_osm_polygon
```

Is there any way to use `IN` to check if the coalesced value is in a set of values, instead of writing separate `WHEN` statements? Something like:

```
WHEN x IN ('park','common','garden','playground')
```

Instead of:

```
WHEN 'park' THEN 'park'
WHEN 'common' THEN 'park'
WHEN 'garden' THEN 'park'
WHEN 'playground' THEN 'park'
```

Comment: Perhaps: `case when coalesce(landuse,leisure, highway, amenity, tourism) = 'industrial' THEN 'industrial'
     WHEN coalesce(landuse,leisure, highway, amenity, tourism) in ('park','common','garden','playground') THEN 'park'
else 'other'end as class`

Comment: @xQbert I think that should be an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two approaches to using `case`:

`Case X when Y then Z  When A then B else C end`...

or 
`case when X = Y and A=B then Z when X=Y and A=C then Y end`

The second option gives you greater flexibility and allows compound criteria to be used.
so...

```
CASE WHEN coalesce(landuse,leisure, highway, amenity, tourism) = 'industrial' 
     THEN 'industrial' 
     WHEN coalesce(landuse,leisure, highway, amenity, tourism) in   
                  ('park','common','garden','playground') 
     THEN 'park' 
     ELSE 'other'
END as class
```

Answer (score 1):

As in your question, use can use `when x in ('a', 'b', 'c')...`, however, to avoid repetition, it's better to use inline view like this:

```
select
  way,
  way_area,
  case when x in ('park','common','garden','playground') then 'park'
       when x = 'industrial' then 'industrial'
       else 'other'
  end as class
from (select way, way_area, COALESCE(landuse, leisure, highway, amenity, tourism) x
      from planet_osm_polygon
      where...) as t
```

Once you aliased (as `x` here) the `coalesce(...)`, you can refer it in the query. Then you can use it in `case`~`when` expression. You can also use `in` within `case`~`when` expression.